# How to install fileManager node module in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am having some problem with installing fileManager on Ubuntu 16.04. It is giving me some errors when I run the following command:

```
npm install -g node-file-manager
```

Here is what I see on running the command:

[image]

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just like every time you get permission denied errors, try running it using `sudo`...

```
sudo npm install -g node-file-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install -g node-file-manager
```